# find records in model based on conditions of associated model

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I need a way to find all the records in a model depending on conditions of one of its associated models.
Something like this:

```
Product.where(:product_number => [1,3,5], customer.city => "New New York")
```

which would return all products whose customer's city is New New York and has a product number of either 1, 3, or 5.

My product table has a customer_id column, so I could probably just find all customers whose city is New New York, grab their id's, and then use `:customer_id => customerIdArray`, but is there a simpler way, like in my example? Perhaps using something like `customer.city` or `customer[:city]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
Product.joins(:customer).where('products.product_number in (:product_list) and customers.city = :customer_city', product_list: [1, 3, 5], customer_city: 'New New York')
```

Comment: Well it looks like that did the trick. Thanks a lot, mate. May your sword stay sharp and your steed be quick.